CiviMail: Issue with Scheduled Emails: Cron Job Success but No Deliveries Received [Solved]
I'm feeling a bit embarrassed because, despite using CiviCRM for many years, this is my first attempt at using the Scheduled Mail function.
Currently, I'm running CiviCRM 5.71.1 alongside WordPress 6.5 and PHP 7.4.33. In the Outbound Mail settings, I've configured SMTP with the following details:

SMTP Server: smtp.mandrillapp.com
SMTP Port: 587
Authentication: Yes

My CiviCRM instance can send transactional emails through Mandrillapp without issues. Recipients receive these emails, and Mandrillapp's Outbound activity logs them properly.
However, I'm now testing the scheduled mailings feature. I've created several test mailings and scheduled them for later delivery. All of these mailing statuses show as completed. The 'Send Scheduled Mailings' cron indicates successful processing, as shown below:

Starting execution of Send Scheduled Mailings
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Success (a:1:{s:9:"processed";i:5;})

However, I haven't received these test emails. Additionally, when I check the CiviMail section, it shows that there have been 0 successful deliveries ('There are currently no Successful Deliveries'). The emails are not logged in the Contact's Activities section either. Furthermore, when I visit the Mandrillapp webpage, I don't see the emails logged in their Outbound activities.
I presume that there's an issue with my CiviMail settings. Could anyone advise on how to rectify this or properly configure CiviMail? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated
Update:
It turns out that I didn't set up the bounced processing correctly.  This issue is now resolved.

I added the Mandrill tag. if you haven't already done so it may be worth clicking it to look for related tickets (if there are any)
